# How to populate image in a dynamic list in codename one

Tags: codenameone

How to populate image in a dynamic list in code name one?

```
protected boolean initListModelList(List cmp) {

 cmp.setModel(new com.codename1.ui.list.DefaultListModel(new String[] {"Firstname", "LastName", "Email"}));
        return true;
}
```

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you used hashtables and a renderer as I explained here: [How to add dynamic data in the renderer created using UI builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134121/how-to-add-dynamic-data-in-the-renderer-created-using-ui-builder/24135463#24135463)

The value in the hashtable or map you used for a specific row can be an image. E.g.:

```
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> a = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
HashMap<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
m.put("firstName", name);
m.put("picture", image);
a.add(m);
... etc for every row
cmp.setModel(new com.codename1.ui.list.DefaultListModel(a));
```