# How to add dynamic data in the renderer created using UI builder?

Tags: codenameone

How to add dynamic data in the renderer created using UI builder?

create a render from ui builder and dynamic data to populate list.

protected boolean initListModelList(List cmp) {

cmp.setModel(new com.codename1.ui.list.DefaultListModel(new String[] {"Firstname", "LastName", "Email"}));
        return true;
}

Answer (score 0):

The renderer doesn't contain the data only the logic for presenting the data. The model is the one that contains the data.

To create a renderer check out this: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-list-of-items-the-hard-way-gui-builder-renderer.html

In that case your model needs to contain hashtables or maps with the keys being the names of the components and the values being the values for the specific entry.

To update the model dynamically just use `setItemAt` on the `DefaultListModel`.