# Codenameone refresh list of images without reloading the page

Tags: codenameone

I am Working on an app with requirement where we need to create a dynamic image gallery which refreshes after few minutes.When refresh happens three things should happen without reloading  the page

1) Obsolete images should be removed
2) New Images should be added 
3) Non Obsolete images should stay (not reload)
4) Images should be stacked next to each other as it will be mostly used on tablet

I was looking at Boxlayout or FlowLayout and I can add the image but I am not sure how to delete it dynamically .I was able to set UUID for the image component but was not able to get component based on UUID to remove it . How can I get component based on its UUID added to the form ? 
 Is this the correct approach ?  or there is already build in component that does that .

I saw this
    [How to add dynamic data in the renderer created using UI builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134121/how-to-add-dynamic-data-in-the-renderer-created-using-ui-builder/24135463#24135463)

```
But I also read using List is discouraged 

https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/list/package-summary.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple to do with a `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` `Container`. When you create an image component to add to the box layout do this:

```
myImageComponent.putClientProperty("imageId", imageId);
```

Then when you have the callback to refresh the list just do something like this:

```
for(Component cmp : parentContainer) {
    String id = (String)myImageComponent.getClientProperty("imageId");
    if(!existsInNewList(id)) {
       cmp.remove();
    }
}
```

When you are done updating the container just call `animateLayout(200)` or `revalidate()` to refresh the UI.

Comment: This worked , animatLayout(200) seems to give  better UI experience

Comment: Yes, just one of the things you can do with Container that you can't do with List... FYI when an answer is correct you should accept it and ideally upvote it which gives both you and the person answering points that are quite useful on SO. You accept an answer by clicking the check box next to the answer.

Comment: A follow-up question, what is the best practice to fetch data. The app will be running (not in background) and images will be pulled every 15 secs. I was thinking of using fetch but I read the documentation and in IOS it is only visual notification and requires human interaction. 

"iiOS will only deliver the push notification to the app, if it is running or
if the user clicked the push notification popup!".                                         Is polling better option or is there any other way?

Comment: There is no reason to use that for something that runs in the foreground. Just use a connection request and fetch the image. When the `postResponse` callback of the connection request completes check if 15 seconds elapsed if so make a request again, if not schedule a timer for the remaining duration. Notice that this might be a battery drain so I suggest suspending it if `Display.isMinimized()` returns true.