# codenameone Picker Alternative to ComboBox

Tags: combobox, codenameone, picker

I am getting my feet wet with `Codename One`.  I have looked into more other options like `Xamarin`, `PhoneGap`, `Ionic` for cross platform but I kinda got hooked with `Codename one` as it really code once and run anywhere.

I've been going through ui elements and I am kinda blocked on populating a `combobox` (Alternative is `Picker`)

Let's say I have stores as value pair (`storeId`, `storeName`). I want to display the `storeName` in `Picker` but keep `storeId` as the value reference.
Once the store is selected I would like to pass the `storeId` to an API call.
Is this possible.  This might be very simple question but seems bit difficult to implement (I am really new to mobile).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our recommendation is to [avoid ComboBox](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-dont-use-combobox.html). It's a UI pattern that doesn't exist on iOS natively and would feel alien on modern phones. It exists in Codename One.

In this code from the sample above you can get a similar effect to a complex multi-field combo box:

```
Form hi = new Form("Button", BoxLayout.y());

String[] characters = { "Tyrion Lannister", "Jaime Lannister", "Cersei Lannister"};
String[] actors = { "Peter Dinklage", "Nikolaj Coster-Waldau", "Lena Headey"};
int size = Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(7);
EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(Image.createImage(size, size, 0xffcccccc), true);
Image[] pictures = {
    URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "tyrion","http://i.lv3.hbo.com/assets/images/series/game-of-thrones/character/s5/tyrion-lannister-512x512.jpg"),
    URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "jaime","http://i.lv3.hbo.com/assets/images/series/game-of-thrones/character/s5/jamie-lannister-512x512.jpg"),
    URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "cersei","http://i.lv3.hbo.com/assets/images/series/game-of-thrones/character/s5/cersei-lannister-512x512.jpg")
};

MultiButton b = new MultiButton("Pick A Lanister...");
b.addActionListener(e -> {
    Dialog d = new Dialog();
    d.setLayout(BoxLayout.y());
    d.getContentPane().setScrollableY(true);
    for(int iter = 0 ; iter < characters.length ; iter++) {
        MultiButton mb = new MultiButton(characters[iter]);
        mb.setTextLine2(actors[iter]);
        mb.setIcon(pictures[iter]);
        d.add(mb);
        mb.addActionListener(ee -> {
            b.setTextLine1(mb.getTextLine1());
            b.setTextLine2(mb.getTextLine2());
            b.setIcon(mb.getIcon());
            d.dispose();
            b.revalidate();
        });
    }
    d.showPopupDialog(b);
});
hi.add(b);
hi.show();
```

[image]

If you insist on using a `ComboBox` you can use a model to give it any object data you want. Then create a cell render to display the data. This is all discussed in depth in the [component section of Codname One's developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html). Notice that since `ComboBox` derives from `List` a lot of the `List` tips and docs apply to `ComboBox`.

Comment: Thank you Shai for the quick response.  I do realize that the combo box is not the way to go and I like the idea of Multibutton.  Only thing I am not sure still is how to retrieve the id of the selected item.

I am sure there should be a way to get the value of the selected item.  I'll give it a try.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use get/putClientProperty() to store meta-data on the components see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774454/codenameone-refresh-list-of-images-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: Thank you Shai.  I'll give it a try.  I've been really enjoying this.